# What does #QNANO signify or mean in C?

Tags: c, vector, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int n;

struct vector
{
  int dir[100];
};
int dot(struct vector v1, struct vector v2)
{
  int dp,j;
  dp=0;
  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
    dp = dp + (v1.dir[j]*v2.dir[j]);
  }
return dp;
}
float cosine(int vdot, float v1mod, float v2mod)
{
  float cos1, vdo = vdot;
  cos1 = (vdot/(v1mod*v2mod));
  return cos1;
}
  float modul(struct vector v1)
{
  int j;
  float v1mod;
  float deg = 0;
  for(j=0; j<n; j++)
   {
     deg = deg + ((v1.dir[j])*(v1.dir[j]));
   }
 v1mod = sqrt(deg);
}
int main()
  {
    int j;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    struct vector v1;
    struct vector v2;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
         scanf("%d", &v1.dir[j]);
      }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
         printf("%d/", v1.dir[j]);
      }
    printf("\n");

    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
         scanf("%d", &v2.dir[j]);
      }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
         printf("%d/", v2.dir[j]);
      }
         printf("\n");

    int vdot;

    float v1mod, v2mod, cos2;

    vdot = dot(v1,v2);
    printf("%d\n", vdot);

    v1mod = modul(v1);
    printf("%f\n", v1mod);

    v2mod = modul(v2);
    printf("%f\n", v2mod);

    cos2 = cosine(vdot, v1mod, v2mod);

    printf("cosine = %f\n", cos2);
  }
```

When we compile the code, the output for cosine is showing "1.#QNANO.
I checked all the websites, but no where did I find the right reason for the occurrence of the
error.
Also can some one specify how many such more error types are there . 
**The bug in the code is intentional.

Comment: Not a number (for example, `sqrt(-1,2)` or `pow(0,0)`).

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: This code does not compile `modul()` is missing a return value.  Since this cannot therefore be the code you are running, how can we be sure that it exhibits the error you are asking about?  Also the program operated in user input data - to be able to reproduce your problem we would need to know the input test data.

Comment: I know there is a bug, what I want to know is about what the #QNAN0 means and what does it signify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Q` probably means it's a [quiet not-a-number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Quiet_NaN). The `O` might mean overflow.

What exact platform and compiler did you use?

Comment: I am using mingw in Code blocks.

Comment: Does it mean that the out put is not a real no. ??

Comment: @JahangirAli Read the page I linked to, you seem unaware of NaNs.

Comment: @unwind-Thanks a lot. Really was unare.

Answer (score 0):

So I was running a few codes and doing some experiments and came across this Error. (#QNANO)
The most valid explanation I could come up with is the data specifier mismatch i.e have a look at this simple code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a,c;
  a = 2;
  float b;
  b = 3;
  c = a*b;
  printf("%f",c);
  return 0;
}
```

The output of this simple code is -1 #QNANO, so I assume that as an integer variable was multiplied by a floating variable and the result was stored in an integer variable but when we print the value of c and we do that with %f, then the integer variable cannot be converted to float and hence the error throws up.